# How to save an image which only display properly using imshow(grayImg,[])?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am working on an image encryption project, so I first converts color image to gray and do the rest, after encryption I can see the image **only using**

```
imshow(grayImg,[])
```

Not by

```
imshow(grayImg)
```

but if I store the image with

```
imwrite(grayImg,outputFileName);
```

Then it isn't saving as expected or not as I saw when using **imshow(grayImg,[])**
Does anyone know what kind of error am I making?

Comment: `imshow(grayImg,[])` **scales** the grayscale image. I suspect that when you say you can't see the image otherwise, that you **can** see the image, it's just all (or mostly) black. The problem would be a lot easier to diagnose if you attached the image that you saved and were a little more precise in the wording of your question.

Comment: You need to add a mapping like: `imwrite(X,map,'im.png')`. [] makes image scale between minimum and maximum values you have in the image. If you normalize betwwen 0 and 1 before hand or convert into a different format in which scaling is predefined, you wouldn't need [] parameter. (i.e. Convert to uint8 using `imnew = uint8((im/max(im(:)))*255)` )

Comment: Converting to uint8 is working, Thanks